# I think SSL (HTTPS) is able to breach, agree?

Tags: ssl

by a middle router that makes a proxy of public key and replaces all later occurrences of public key to make browser not understand. We can see how protocol works and target to confuse it.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what information you are interested in.

Comment: am I right? or my thinking is not right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can place an HTTPS proxy in the middle that will generate fake certificates for the client, but to make the client trust those forged certificates you will need to register the proxy as a trusted Certificate Authority, otherwise the browser (or ssh terminal or whatever) will inform you that an invalid certifcate has been produced, since providing a fake public key will break the signature of the webservers real certification authorities.

Obviously if the user ignores the warnings from the browser and accepts this forged certificates anyway, the security is broken.